# Find variance for $X$ such that $0 \leq X \leq 1$.

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a random variable such that $0 \leq X \leq 1$. I have to show that $var(X) \leq \frac{1}{4}$. A hint is given, which says that if $\mathbb{E}[X] = m$, then prove first that $\mathbb{E}[A] = \mathbb{E}[B]$ for $A := \frac{1}{4}-(X-m)^2$ and $B:=(\frac{1}{2}-m)^2 + X(1-X)$.

So far I was able to prove the hint, i.e. $\mathbb{E}[A] = \mathbb{E}[B] = \frac{1}{4} - \mathbb{E}[X^2]$. Then I get:

$var(X) = \mathbb{E}[X^2] - \mathbb{E}[X]^2 = \frac{1}{4} - \mathbb{E}[A] - m^2$

My idea now is to say that since $0 \leq X \leq 1$, we have that $X^2 \leq X \Rightarrow \mathbb{E}[X^2] \leq \mathbb{E}[X] \leq \mathbb{E}[X]^2$ and on the other side we always have $\mathbb{E}[X]^2 \leq \mathbb{E}[X^2]$, therefore $\mathbb{E}[X^2] = \mathbb{E}[X]^2 = m^2$. Is that right? That's the step where I'm not entirely sure. If that is the case, then I'd have:

$var(X) = m^2 - m^2 = 0 \leq \frac{1}{4}$, which is weird, because I doubt that the task ends with saying that it's $\leq \frac{1}{4}$ by showing it's $0$. So there has to be a mistake somewhere.

EDIT:
The first mistake was to say that $\mathbb{E}[X] \leq \mathbb{E}[X]^2$. It's even the opposite in this case.

Comment: You can't say $E[X]<E[X]^2$.

Comment: Yes right, that was mistake, thank you. Any idea how to solve it? Any hint?

Comment: Actually, $\mathbb{E}[A]=1/4-\mathbb{E}[(X-m)^2]=1/4-\mathbb{E}[(X-\mathbb{E}[X])^2]=1/4-var[X]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at $B$, you can conclude that $E[B]\geq 0$, which also implies $E[A]\geq 0$. So $1/4-E[A]-m^2\leq 1/4$ which finishes the proof.

Comment: Thank you. How do you see that $\mathbb{E}[A] \geq 0$ and $\mathbb{E}[B] \geq 0$ though?

Comment: @J.C.: $B=(1/2-m)^2+X(1-X)$. The two terms here are always nonnegative, hence so is the expectation.

Comment: That was too obvious. *facepalm* Thank you a lot! That finishes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Because $|X-1/2|\le 1/2$, $\Bbb E[(X-1/2)^2]\le 1/4$. Write $|mu$ for $\Bbb E[X]$. Then ${\rm var}[X]=\Bbb E[(X-\mu)^2]\le\Bbb E[(X-1/2)^2]\le 1/4$.

Comment: This requires the lemma that $\mu = \arg \min_m E((X-m)^2)$, though.

Comment: And if one has learned anything about the variance of a random variable, one has learned that.